# URL rewriting from .htaccess to web.config in Zend Framwork 2

Tags: .htaccess, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2 for developing an application in PHP. Everything works locally (apache server on linux).

But now I have to deploy my site to a Windows Server (using IIS, on Azure).

As IIS doesn't read the .htaccess I have to rewrite it on a web.config file. This is what I've done using the IIS7 import rewrite rule feature. [More informations here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

Unfortunetly ISS can't translate the rules to the web config..

This is where I need your help.

Here is my .htaccess file (default one from Zend Framework 2)

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

### Edit

After some researches I've found that -s and -l (first two conditions) can be replaced with -f. Perfect!

So my real problem is focused on the last two rules. (ISS can convert the E=.. and the ENV:.. syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is my final solution.
Everything works and follows my expectations (I added the fact that I didn't want to see the /public in the URL).

Read the code comments for a better understanding.

```
<!-- Rewrite rules -->
<!-- Below is some rules in order to have a beautiful URL on the client side.
    + Each requests to a /public/something urls are transferred to a /something url
    + If the /public/requestFile exists we serve it
    + If the requested file exists  we serve it
    + If no other rules has matched then we send the request to our public/index.php file             (default behavior from Zend Framework 2)
-->
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Permanent redirect of requests on /public/something to /something -->
    <rule name="Redirect public " stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^public/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

     <!-- If the file/directory requested exist in /public, we serve it. -->
    <rule name="Search in public" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public{URL}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />  
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoeCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- If the file/directory requested exist, we serve it. -->
    <rule name="Direct files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- If no previous rules have matched, then we send the request to public/index (url rewriting
        used by Zend -->
    <rule name="Url rewriting" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks to **Ruben** for the help!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked. Did you have to write the rules by hand or did the import function of IIS take care of most of the hard work as the docs suggest?

Comment: No, I've used import function in IIS for some rules. Then I've done some updates to fit my needs. But your advice was a great help! BTW, I've never seen a reference to URL rewriting in the docs?

Comment: It's in the Getting Started guide, right here at the bottom of the page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Answer (score 1):

From the ZF2 docs:

If you're are using IIS with the URL Rewrite Module, import the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was a really good start to find the final solution!